# Unity3D: Camera is unable to move with firstperson script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The object is a satellite type so I have a script to move the object in an orbit using its position. And I also have a script to move the satellite object in first person mode.

Problem is that the user is unable to move the camera by the axis "Mouse X" and "Mouse Y" for first person mode. The problem is happening because the orbit script and the first person script are both controlling the camera so it is unable to move. In the game, when you move the mouse you see the camera jerk and when I disable the orbit script, the first person works.

How can I fix this problem?

A solution can be to use only position for the orbit, and the rotation for first person control?? The first person mode will not control the objects position only rotation. The orbit will not control the objects rotation only position.

Thank you!

**Orbit Script**

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.RotateAround(centerOfOrbit.position, orbitAxis, orbitSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    desiredOrbitPosition = (transform.position - centerOfOrbit.position).normalized * orbitRadius + centerOfOrbit.position;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, desiredOrbitPosition, Time.deltaTime * orbitAdjustSpeed);
}
```

**First Person mode control (does not work with Orbit)**

```
private void Update()
{
    if(allowFirstPerson)
    {
        x+= Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * turnSpeed;
        if (allowTiltingForward)
        {
            y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * turnSpeed;
        }

        y = ClampAngle(y, minVerticalAngle, maxVerticalAngle);
        if (minHorizontalAngle != 0 || maxHorizontalAngle != 0)
        {
            x = ClampAngle(x, minHorizontalAngle, maxHorizontalAngle);
        }
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);
        Vector3 direction = (rotation * Vector3.forward * 100);
        aimPoint = new Vector3(direction.x + aimError, direction.y + aimError, direction.z + aimError);
        aimDir = (aimPoint - playerCamera.transform.position).normalized;
    }
}
```

This Top View mode control works with the Orbit script but the top view does not use the same controls as the first person but I can not seem to figure out why one works and the other does not.

**Top View mode control (does work with Orbit)**

```
private void Update()
{
    if(allowTopView)
    {
        Ray ray = playerCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        topDownAimPoint = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
           topDownAimPoint = hit.point;
        }
        aimPoint = new Vector3(topDownAimPoint.x + aimError, topDownAimPoint.y + aimError, topDownAimPoint.z + aimError);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that your problem is caused by two scripts trying to set the rotation for the same object: a camera. If this is the case, you can create an empty `Satellite` object and make the camera a child of that object in the Hierarchy. Attaching the Orbit Script to the `Satellite` object and the First Person script to the camera will allow the camera to move in the satellite's orbit but still have its own independent rotation.

**EDIT:**

To accommodate a 3d model in this situation, create an empty parent object called `SatteliteWrapper` (or something similar) and attach the Orbit Script to that object. Then make the camera a child of `SatteliteWrapper` and make the 3d model a child of the camera. That allows the model to rotate with the camera.

Comment: Yes but I still need the objects front to be aiming straight with the camera

Comment: Do you mean that you have a 3d model for the satellite? In that case you would create an empty parent object called `SatteliteWrapper` or something similar and attach the Orbit Script to that object. Then you would make the camera a child of `SatteliteWrapper` and make the 3d model a child of the camera. Does that describe your situation? If so I'll update my answer.

Comment: I've edited my original answer to include the previous comment. If everything is working now, please consider marking my answer as accepted.

Comment: The satellite object goes invisible when I make it a child of the camera?

Comment: Is it possible that instead of going invisible it’s just getting moved somewhere else? I’d check the coordinates of the Satellite in the Inspector and make sure the position stays zero. There also shouldn’t be any scripts attached to the satellite itself, just to the wrapper and the camera. Also double-check which layer the satellite is on.

Comment: yes it becomes invisible, coordinates are all zero. Problem is I have several satellites switching first person views, so the camera is consistently being moved. The first person script is also a shooting script. I can not just make a wrapper with a camera child and the sat a child of that.

Comment: I added another way to control the satellite but it does not work the same as first person but the orbit still works, so whats the difference